# Can I access pointer to base instance from derived instance in C++?

Tags: c++

1. I have a base class and a derived class and a bunch of methods defined as virtual which are overridden in the derived class.
2. I have an instance of the derived class assigned to a base pointer "myPointer" so the derived class virtual methods are called.
3. Is it possible to "cast" the "myPointer" to a pointer pointing to the actual base instance and hence the base virtual methods are invoked through the new "casted pointer"?.
4. I know about `myPointer->Base::MyMethod();` so that is not what I want.  I want to do something like:

   ```
   Base* myPointer = new Derived();
   Base* actualBasePointer = (some kind of case) myPointer;
   actualBasePointer->MyMethod(); // this invokes the base virtual method.
   ```

Comment: Well, you could copy the object using *object slicing*, but that's not the same as casting

Comment: Regarding point 4, *why* don't you want to do something like that? What is the *real* and *actual* problem you want to solve? What is the reason for you wanting the "base instance"?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Simply make `MyMethod()`, in the base class, consist of nothing but a call to `BaseMyMethod()`, then use it whenever you wish the "real" base method to be called.

Comment: In what way do you hope your hypothetical `actualBasePointer->MyMethod()` call would behave differently than `myPointer->Base::MyMethod()` call? What is it you don't like about the latter, that you hope to "fix" with the former?

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: `actualBasePointer->MyMethod()` behaves differently from what OP intends if `Base::MyMethod()` itself calls another virtual method of `Base`, which has been overridden in `Derived`
.

Comment: @StephanLechner Well OK, if one wants to completely discard the `Derived` identify, then slicing it is: `Base actualBase = *myPointer; actualBase.MyMethod();` Won't work for arbitrary `Base` (e.g. one that is an abstract class).

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: right, I think OP looks for "slicing" as a view, i.e. without the need of making a copy of parts of the orignial object. Doesn't virtual inheritance maintain such "views" to base objects?

Comment: @StephanLechner Virtual inheritance merely ensures that there's only one instance of the base class in a diamond-shaped hierarchy. Virtual function calls are still dynamically dispatched to the override in most-derived class.

Comment: The reason I is this:

Comment: The reason is this: I got a program from someone in which it has an object instance that it works if it is instantiated once (because it contains a lot of hardware initialization stuff.)  I want to derive a mock class to do testing.  I instantiate the mock instance and run the program with the mock a couple of times.  After that I want to go into the normal logic using the base instance - I have a single derived instance but I need to run the same program via both the mock and base implementation.

Answer (score 2):

A `Base*` is a `Base*`. There is no "variant" that disables virtual dispatch / polymorphism, nor is there a type of cast to give you a different kind of pointer that does so.

Either your functions are `virtual` or they're not, and it would be really confusing if you could switch that on and off.

Instead, have alternative, non-virtual functions in your class that do what you need. I would recommend that you find a way to make these `private` to avoid confusion with the existing `public` virtual functions — generally this means they will be purely for utility/internal purposes. If this means you can't use them for the goal you have in mind, I'd advise reviewing your approach.

Alternatively, stick with the clear and well-known `myPointer->Base::MyMethod()` — simply knowing about it already doesn't seem like a good reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Though a derived class object is composed out of its base class objects as far as non-static data members are concerned, the connection between virtual methods to their implementations in the derived class (or the base class, if a method is not overridden) is fixed and tightly coupled with the derived class object. So there is no way to generate a "view to the object's `vtable`" as if it where that of a Base class object. You can just refer directly to a specific implementation of a method by writing `myPointer->Base::MyMethod()`, yet this must be expressed explicitly with each call and it will not prohibit dynamic binding if `Base::MyMethod()` itself calls other virtual methods.

The only way to achieve that the derived class object behaves like a base class object is using object slicing, i.e. assigning a derived class object to an instance (not a pointer or reference) of the base class:

```
class Base {
public:
    int x = 10;

    virtual void printX() const {
        printInt(x);
    }
protected:
    virtual void printInt(int i) const {
        cout << "Base_printInt: " << i;
    }
};

class Derived : public virtual Base {
protected:
    virtual void printInt(int i) const override {
        cout << "Derived_printInt: " << i;
    }

};

int main() {
    Derived d;

    Base b = static_cast<Base>(d);

    b.printX();
}
```

Output:

```
Base_printInt: 10
```

Comment: Doesn't this make a copy?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot disable virtual dispatch in any such manner.
However I would recommend this design pattern if you do need this behavior.

```
class StaticBase { 

    void foo() { /*default implementation*/ }

} 

class VirtualBase : StaticBase {

   StaticBase& as_base() { 
       return static_cast<StaticBase&>(*this); 
   }

   virtual void foo() { return StaticBase::foo(); }
}

class Derived : VirtualBase { 

   virtual void foo() { /* specialization */ }
}
```

That way you can do things like....

```
VirtualBase* vbase = new Derived(); 
vbase->foo();            //derived implementation 
vbase->as_base().foo();  //default implementation
```